# HTML5 Canvas how to automatically keep track of text user input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

This is the code if you want to try it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/csCoder/eLxfrn10/8/

I currently have 2 textboxes from the user will type in their input and when they press "draw line", then the input is read and a line is drawn accordingly. I want to make it so that the line will automatically be drawn whenever the user inputs anything in the textbox (without having to click on a button) OR whenever the user uses the slider.
Currently the lines that I drew changed based on what is typed into the textbox. However, I have a slider that updates the text box and I want my program to keep track of the slider AND the textboxes instead of just the textboxes if that makes sense. I appreciate your help!

This is what it looks like right now:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq1Ll.png)

I cleaned up the code to make it easier and more relevant:
This code snippet represents the slider and the textbox (user should be able to use either to input numbers).

```
<input id="rangeInputM" type="range" min="-10" max="10" oninput="m1.value=rangeInputM.value" />
<input id="m1" type="number" value="1" min="-200" max="200" oninput="rangeInputM.value=m1.value" />
```

This is where I am having trouble getting my drawing to update whenever I either input new text or move the slider. Using #m1 as the selector works for updating the text box, but I am trying to get both the textbox (#m1) and the slider (#rangeInputM) to work:

```
$("#rangeInputM").keyup(function(){
    
    var m1,b1 = 0;

    m1 = parseFloat($("#m1").val());
    b1 = parseFloat($("#b1").val());

   
    var myGraph = new Graph({
     canvasId: 'Graph',
     minX: -10,
     minY: -10,
     maxX: 10,
     maxY: 10,
     unitsPerTick: 1
    });      
    
    myGraph.drawLine(m1, b1, 'blue', 3);
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$("m1")` will target an element `<m1></m1>`. I doubt this is what you have in your code that you should show in the question itself btw. If `m1` is the `id` of an element, then the selector is `#m1`.

Comment: I edited my post to show the code easier. Right now, m1 is the id, but even if I have the selector as #m1 instead of just m1, nothing changes.

Comment: It does change for me.

Comment: Please only post the code that's needed to reproduce your problem. No one is going to debug 1000 lines of code for your problem. It's also not really clear to me what should happen and why it doesn't work?

Comment: I edited my post to make it so that it only contains relevant code. I did some debugging and now #m1 does in fact work, but the slider that it corresponds with does not work, so I was wondering how I would change it from .keyup to maybe something else? If the selector is #m1, it works (since this is the text box) but if the selector is #rangeInputM, this does not work (since this is the slider)

Comment: Move away from the ugly inline event handlers on the input fields, `oninput="m1.value=rangeInputM.value"` - replace that with properly added event handlers, same as you are already doing for the button. Then inside those callback functions, execute the same functionality as you do on the button click, resp. simply trigger that one using `$('#btnGraph').trigger('click')`

Comment: To clarify, I do NOT want to use a button and want it to automatically update whenever the user types in the textbox or uses the slider